# FluentNhibernate Mapping Dictionaries Foreign Key Remains Null

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have a simple Fluent-NHibernate mapping that gives me a headache! I'm trying to map a dictionary for one of the entities, but its FK remains null.

Here's the entities code:

```
public class Person
{
    public Person()
    {
        PhoneNumbers = new Dictionary<string, Phone>();
    }

    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual IDictionary<string, Phone> PhoneNumbers { get; set; }
}

public class Phone
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Type { get; set; }
    public virtual string Number { get; set; }
}
```

Now, Here's the mapping:

```
public class PersonClassMap : ClassMap<Person>
{
    public PersonClassMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity();
        Map(x => x.Name);
        HasMany(x => x.PhoneNumbers).AsMap(y => y.Type).Cascade.All();
    }
}

public class PhoneClassMap : ClassMap<Phone>
{
    public PhoneClassMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Identity();
        Map(x => x.Type);
        Map(x => x.Number);
    }
}
```

Last, Here's the Test I'm doing:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ConfigureSessionFactory();

        using (var session = _sessionFactory.OpenSession())
        {
            var john = new Person();
            john.Name = "John";

            Phone home = new Phone
                             {
                                 Type = "Home",
                                 Number = "12345"
                             };

            john.PhoneNumbers.Add(home.Type, home);

            session.Save(john);
        }
    }
```

For some reason, when I look in the database, the phone record's `Person_id` remains null, and when I load the person back from the DB, the `PhoneNumbers` dictionary remains empty.

Why? And how to solve this issue? What am I mapping wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was finally resolved by adding Transactions. I have no idea why that works (which makes me quite sad, actually), but it does.

```
using (var session = _sessionFactory.OpenSession())
{
    var transaction = session.BeginTransaction();
    john.Name = "John";

    Phone home = new Phone
                     {
                         Type = "Home",
                         Number = "12345"
                     };
     john.PhoneNumbers.Add(home.Type, home);
     session.Save(john);
     transaction.Commit();
}
```

Hope that helps you too, as it took me 3 hours too long to get this right.